# Entity framework database fist for set tables with different prefix?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have one databese which uses a set of tables. For example: CompanyName$Table1, CompanyName$Table2 and OtherCompanyName$Table1, OtherCompanyName$Table2.
CompanyName$Table1 and OtherCompanyName$Table1 have only different names. I use entity framework database fist and create edmx file for tables CompanyName$Table1, CompanyName$Table2. How i can use the same edmx file for tables OtherCompanyName$Table1, OtherCompanyName$Table2 and take CompanyName from config file?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have many options here. I thought you might be able to get away with having two schemas, one for each company, with the same tables in them but different permissions to the schema for each company. However, the model edmx file contains the schema name so that won't work.

All that leaves I think is having one database per company and giving a separate connection string to each company. There is a small overhead to having extra databases, but it's not huge in terms of resources - though it could cause management problems if you have hundreds of companies.